# Could not resolve assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, .net-standard-2.0, msbuild-task

I created a sample class library with .netstandard 2.0 as target framework. I added assembly Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core with Version=17.4.0. I created a class derived from **Task** class from the above assembly to execute MSBuild task in vs 2022.

After compilation, I have used the assembly inside .net 6.0 targeted console application. While running the console application, it is giving me the error "**Could not resolve assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'**".

When checked the assembly with dnSpy, it showing "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0" in reference instead of v17.4.0.

I tried both compiling from vs 2022 and from developer command propmt using "dotnet build", but still same issue.

Could anybody please help me to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and as far as I can see, that's an problem in the package, because the Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll is saying it supports .NET Standard while missing in the expected .NET Standard version in the lib folder inside the package.
The dll is only available in .net 4.7.2 and .NET 7.0
[image: Package inspection in dotPeek]

It should work if you use Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core with Version=17.3.2 because in that case your .NET 6 application would use the .NET 6 dll in the package. in 17.4.0 that library was replaced with it's .NET 7 version.

This msbuild issue seems to be about the same problem https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/8166